# pdflatex cannot find PDF file

Tags: graphics

I have read all all related posts to my problem and can find no solution. I am trying to load a pdf file made from MS Excel. The MS Excel content is a table; I have turned off all headers and footers, set the print area to the table only, and included no bookmarks, etc. from the pdf export options. Here is the resultant pdf file:

[image: Image created by export from the associated pdf file]

When I try to load the pdf into a minimal TeX file, I get the following error (copied directly from the log file):

```
 LaTeX Warning: File `tables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf' not found on input line 8.
 ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `tables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf' not found.

 See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

 l.8 ...width=0.5\textwidth]{tables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf}
```

Here is the latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/tables}}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf}
    \caption{test plot.}
    \label{fig:abc}
\end{table}
%
\end{document}
```

I set the graphics path in the preamble, but it seems to be of no help.

If I drop a different PDF into this folder it loads fine. It seems to be something to do with the fact that the pdf is made of a excel layout, as pdfs built in Inkscape have no issue loading.

Lastly, I am working in TeXstudio on a Windows 7 machine, and have made sure that the default compiler is pdflatex. Thanks for your help. I am totally at a loss.

Comment: Your error message says that the file under `figures` directory can't be found, but your code has `.tables`

Comment: Yes. Minor mistake on my part trying different folders. The same error occurs whether the PDF is in .tables/ or .figures/

Comment: What is the correct name of the file? Is it really in subfolder `.tables` (note the `.` at the very beginning of the name). Please edit you question to show the real message from the `log` file of the shown `tex` file. And why do you use `\graphicspath` *and* a path in `\includegraphics`?

Comment: I used \graphicspath as an attempt to utilize someone else's solution. If I remove it I get the same error. It does not matter. The filename is as it is spelled.

Comment: also please add the projects directory layout, especially: where is the *.tex file relative to the *.pdf lile.

Comment: The PDF is in /tables. The *.tex file is in the directory which holds /tables. I tried placing the PDF in the directory with the *.tex file and it made no difference.

Comment: @SurfProc: I am no Windows user, but is a `.` at the beginning of a folder name possible in Windows?

Comment: Thanks. I tried table/..., and it did not make a difference.

Comment: I am able to successfully compile the code in TeXworks. It would seem to be an issue specific to TeXstudio. Hoping this helps someone track down the problem.

Comment: Please correct your question and add missing information! If you give us incorrect information we cannot help but only speculate!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be answered correctly or meaningfully based on the conflicting and erroneous information provided by the OP.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: if you specofy that the file is in a directory called `.tables` when it is not in that directory it will not work in texworks or any other editor and it does not matter what software made the pdf. It's simply a typo in the filename, as reported by the error message.

Comment: @Mico: That's a bit early...

Comment: I'm voting to close  because it is a failure to input a file simply due to a typo in the filename,

Comment: It is a PDF file writing problem from MS Excel, that is the case. I am happy to provide the original PDF and the one created from Inkscape so others can test. It is not a typo in the filename.

Comment: It's still a typo. With `\graphicspath{{/tables}}` the `\includegraphics[…]{tables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf}` results in loading file `/tablestables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf`, but there isn't a directory `tablestables` in your root directory. If there is a  subdirectory `tables` in your working directory and a file `Ch_Tab_1.pdf` in this subdirectory (we still do not know this) remove the `\graphicspath`. It is not a problem of excel or Inkscape.

Comment: If you're still interested, I would be happy to test with those two files.

Comment: By what means shall I provide them?

Comment: Dropbox for example, or some other file sharing service.

Comment: Placing them in DropBox now.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57043/discussion-on-question-by-surfproc-pdflatex-cannot-find-pdf-file).

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

If `tables` is the name of a subdirectory under the directory that contains your main tex file, then

```
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{.tables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf}
```

contains a typo. It should almost certainly be

```
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tables/Ch1_Tab_1.pdf}
```

instead. Can you spot the difference? By the way, if the file is in pdf format, it's not necessary to specify the extension `.pdf`.

Similarly, `\graphicspath{{./tables}}` is almost certainly incorrect. My guess -- it's just a guess at this point because I don't have access to your computer -- that it should be `\graphicspath{{tables/}}`. On the other hand, if you provide (correctly specified) relative paths as part of `\includegraphics`, it shouldn't be necessary to set the `\graphicspath` macro.

Comment: Thanks Mico. That was pointed out, and it makes no difference. I am usually on linux. Anyways, .tables vs. tables makes no difference.

Comment: @SurfProc - In that case, *the pdf file is not located in the  `tables` subdirectory* (or the `.tables` subdirectory either)! Where it is actually located is not something readers of this site can help you with, I'm afraid. You'll have to the search on your own. I'm going to suggest to close this query for being unanswerable based on the information you've provided.

Comment: Thanks Mico. But I respectfully disagree. The file in question is precisely where it is stated to be - table/. I incidentally just found the solution, but not an answer. If I import the MS Excel created pdf to Inkscape and re-export it as a PDF it loads just fine, from the table/ directory. There is something a miss with how MS Excel creates the PDF file.

Comment: @SurfProc - So now you report the file is in a subdirectory called `table` -- that's rather different from `tables`, isn't it? As I wrote earlier, if LaTeX can't find the file in the subdirectory called `tables`, *it's because the file isn't located in that subdirectory*. Or, equally damagingly, you have failed to correct the `\graphicspath` macro appropriately, thereby making sure that LaTeX's search is being directed toward an incorrect directory...

Comment: I appreciate you point. Here is the code that works just fine:

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}[t]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tables/tab.pdf}
 \caption{test plot.}
 \label{fig:abc}
\end{table}
%
\end{document}

Comment: @SurfProc - So, did the solution consist of removing the faulty `\graphicspath` directive?

Comment: @Mico: Don't argue with O.Ps ;-)

Comment: I am not an expert by any means. But the issue has nothing to do with use of \graphicspath, and has everything to do with how MS Excel writes a PDF file. All I know is that when I write a PDF from Inkscape, the PDF loads just fine into my minimal *.tex. That is all I know - I changed nothing else. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @SurfProc: This unrelated to the content of the PDF; pdftex simply can not find the file.

Comment: The newly exported PDF is in the tables/ directory, as it always was. The PDF which loads was exported from Inkscape; I created a .png from the original MS Excel exported PDF and loaded the .png into Inkscape. Then I exported a PDF from Inkscape. Everything loads now. I realize I have some typos in my responses, but those are typos, not errors in folder naming, or the like. I hope this helps someone else in the future. I have spent the last 7 hours on this.

Comment: @SurfProc - So now we're back to the `tables` (not: `table`) subdirectory?

Comment: I give up. You all win. I made some typos in my responses. What matters is it works now, and after randomly trying a different avenue or pursuit. I hope this helps someone else. In summary: (1) open PDF exported from MS Excel in a PDF viewer; (2) export a suitable graphic file; (3) Load graphic file into Inkscape (other vector graphics package may work); (4) Use the Save a Copy option and save the graphic file as a PDF; (5) Load it into your *.tex within the Table environment.

Comment: @SurfProc everthing you have posted so far points to the fact that you have a typo in the directory name. If you think that is not the case, then please edit your question to fix it so the input you show is the input that you want to use and the error you show is the error from your test file.

Comment: I will try, but I am not sure I have access to editting my questions. I am new to TEX on StackExchange.

Comment: your steps (1) to (4) are unrelated to the problem, the issue is at step (5) you need to put the correct filename, otherwise tex will not find the file. But if you saved the original table as png then just include the png file, do not convert to pdf first.

Comment: I am finished arguing with all of you. This has been enjoyable. Till next time. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score -2):

If you export a PDF from Excel and it does not load into `*.tex` using the `\includegraphics` call (with `\usepackage{graphicx}`) within the table environment, try the following steps as they may help:

1. open PDF exported from MS Excel in a PDF viewer;
2. export a suitable graphic file;
3. load graphic file into Inkscape (other vector graphics package may work);
4. Use the Save a Copy option and save the graphic file as a PDF;
5. Load it into your `*.tex` within the Table environment.

This worked for me after trying many different alternatives.

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense.

Comment: It is what it is, and the community view will take it from here. I do not care, because it works. I cannot convince you all this is the case. But it is. I just performed these steps to a second table and it worked.